# Realm Browser / Android Device Monitor?

Tags: android, browser, device, realm, monitor

I was wondering if there is any possible way to view the default.realm file from the android device monitor *live* in the Realm Browser. I am realizing that having to save this file each time I want to check my database is tedious and seemingly unnecessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Realm-Stetho which will give you a live view into a running database: https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm

Answer (score 0):

Now you can also use [Android Realm Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.min60.android.realmbrowser.free), and view your realm files realm time, directly on your android device while testing your app.